# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to  retrieve some data (`coursename`) from one of my tables but the following error is coming all the time

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

the command I am typing is:

```
select bookno,courno,coursename
from booking, course,coursename
where bookno = 6200
and booking.courno = course.courno
and coursename.coursenameno = course.coursenameno
```

I have some tables as described :

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING 
    (BOOKNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
     COURNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
     BOOKDATE DATE,
     BOOKCUSTPAYMENT VARCHAR (20),
     CONSTRAINT PK_BOOK PRIMARY KEY (BOOKNO,COURNO),
     CONSTRAINT FK_BOOK FOREIGN KEY (COURNO) REFERENCES COURSE(COURNO)
     ON DELETE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
    (CUSTNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL, -- creation of primary-key 
     PROFNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL, 
     CUSTFNAME VARCHAR (15),
     CUSTLNAME VARCHAR (15),
     CUSTDOB DATE,
     CUSTPHONEDAY NUMBER (15),
     CUSTPHONEEVE NUMBER (15),
     CONSTRAINT PK_CUST PRIMARY KEY (CUSTNO),
     CONSTRAINT FK_PROF FOREIGN KEY (PROFNO) REFERENCES PROFICIENCY(PROFNO)
     ON DELETE CASCADE);



CREATE TABLE COURSENAME 
    ( COURSENAMENO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
      COURSENAME VARCHAR (20),
      COURSEDESC VARCHAR (120),
      COURSEDAYCOST NUMBER (7,2),
      CONSTRAINT PK_COURSENAME PRIMARY KEY (COURSENAMENO));   


CREATE TABLE COURSE
     (COURNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL, -- creation of primary-key
      COURSTART DATE,
      COUREND DATE,
      COURSENAMENO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
      ACCDAYNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
      FOODNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL,
      TRANSNO NUMBER (4) NOT NULL, 
      CONSTRAINT PK_COURSE PRIMARY KEY (COURNO),
      CONSTRAINT FK_COURSENAME FOREIGN KEY (COURSENAMENO) REFERENCES COURSENAME(COURSENAMENO));
```

I am researching but I cannot figure out what is happening !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when the same column appears in several tables you need to specify which table is the one to be used. As a general rulem its always a good idea to prefix the column with the table (or alias) as improves readability and speeds up parsing.
so, for your query try (changes in upper case)

```
select BOOKING.bookno,BOOKING.courno,COURSENAME.coursename
from booking, course,coursename
where BOOKING.bookno = 6200
and booking.courno = course.courno
and coursename.coursenameno = course.coursenameno
```

Comment: thank you very much !!! I spent 5 hours today trying to resolve this !!!! I am so happy !!!! and you guys help me !!!! thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify from which table the columns in `SELECT` and `WHERE` statements should be retrieved:

```
select booking.bookno, booking.courno, course.coursename
from booking, course, coursename
where booking.bookno = 6200
and booking.courno = course.courno
and coursename.coursenameno = course.coursenameno
```

Also, consider using ANSI SQL-92+ JOIN syntax like so:

```
select booking.bookno, booking.courno, course.coursename
from booking
inner join course on booking.courno = course.courno
inner join coursename on coursename.coursenameno = course.coursenameno
where booking.bookno = 6200
```

See [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs][1] for some reasoning about it.
[1]: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: good to point out the old join style! Upvote!

Comment: jpw !!! thank you !!! super !!!

Answer (score 1):

When a column is ambigious, this means the database doesnt know which column to use from 2 or more different tables.

You must define in the select like this

```
select tablename.bookno,tablename.courno,tablename.coursename
from booking, course,coursename
where tablename.bookno = 6200
and booking.courno = course.courno                <-- Here its correct
and coursename.coursenameno = course.coursenameno <-- Here its correct
```

Change **tablename.** to the correct table where the column is.

Comment: Kay, Super thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

field courno in your select: you haven't defined from which table: course or booking